# Can we make button function inside try block

Tags: java, try-catch

I am trying to make button function inside the try block but its showing me error , below is my code , I am trying to use the function of button inside onAvtivityResult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {return;}

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
        try
          {
            InputStream is = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            final Bitmap bmInImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            bmInImg.getPixels(mPhotoIntArray, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight());
            bmInImg2.getPixels(vPhotoIntArray, 0, bmInImg2.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg2.getWidth(), bmInImg2.getHeight());
            mCannyOutArray = new int[bmInImg2.getWidth() * bmInImg2.getHeight()];
            final Bitmap bmOutImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmInImg2.getWidth(), bmInImg2.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);  
            bmOutImg.setPixels(mCannyOutArray, 0, bmInImg2.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg2.getWidth(), bmInImg2.getHeight());

            Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextButton);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)  {  
                    negative(bmInImg.getHeight(),bmInImg.getWidth(), mPhotoIntArray, mCannyOutArray);
                    bmOutImg.setPixels(mCannyOutArray, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight());   
                    imageview_2.setImageBitmap(bmOutImg);
                    }
                }

            }
catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
```

Error is shown when I keep mouse on `}` of button function :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
```

Comment: You are not closing your OnClickListener bracket or your try bracket

Comment: Where is this code? If it's inside a method, then you have a nested method which is invalid. If it's not inside a method then it needs to be because you cannot execute code outside of a block. I see no situation under which this code would be valid. There is also no `catch`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider How can I handle it in this method ? I update my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't closing your [anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) correctly,

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)  {  
    negative(bmInImg.getHeight(),bmInImg.getWidth(), mPhotoIntArray, mCannyOutArray);
    bmOutImg.setPixels(mCannyOutArray, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), 0, 0, 
        bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight());   
    imageview_2.setImageBitmap(bmOutImg);
  }
}); // <-- close the OnClickListener
```